# Screen.presentPage without animation

Tags: onsen-ui

It is possible to disable the opening animation of the `ons.screen.presentPage()` method?

I'm trying to use a *login page* as a *modal window* when the app is launched and I don't want the up animation, only the down animation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the current Onsen UI ver 1.0.4 has no method to disable the animation.
We plan to make it possible at the next version.